# Celery beat service showing inactive (dead) in python3

Tags: python-3.x, django

here i am using celery version 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with python  version 3.7 and Django version 3.0
here i am unable to schedule tasks and i couldn't understand why its showing inactive(dead)

here are the commands what i am using and the result what i am getting

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl reset-failed celeryd.service
 sudo systemctl restart celeryd
 sudo systemctl status celeryd

 ● celeryd.service - Celery Beat Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celeryd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-04-01 13:08:11 BST; 2min 20s ago
  Process: 4520 ExecStart=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_F
 Main PID: 4520 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 01 13:08:10 ip-xxx systemd[1]: Started Celery Beat Service.
Apr 01 13:08:11 ip-xxx celery[4520]: celery multi v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)
Apr 01 13:08:11 ip-xxx celery[4520]: > Starting nodes...
Apr 01 13:08:11 ip-xxx celery[4520]:         > worker1@ip-xxx: OK
```

here i am sharing my celery log file result also

```
Apr  1 13:20:08 ip-xxx systemd[1]: Reloading.
Apr  1 13:20:08 ip-xxx systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Apr  1 13:20:17 ip-xxx systemd[1]: Stopped Celery Beat Service.
Apr  1 13:20:17 ip-xxx systemd[1]: Started Celery Beat Service.
Apr  1 13:20:18 ip-xxx celery[4868]: #033[1;36mcelery multi v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)#033[0m
Apr  1 13:20:18 ip-xxx celery[4868]: > Starting nodes...
Apr  1 13:20:18 ip-xxx celery[4868]: #011> worker1@ip-xxx: #033[1;32mOK#033[0m
```

here is my /etc/systemd/celerd.conf

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
#CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

CELERY_APP="mcam"

# Absolute path to "manage.py"
# CELERY_BIN="/home/ravi/deploy/mcam/mcam/server/mcam/manage.py"
#CELERY_BIN="/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/python manage.py celery"
CELERY_BIN="/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery"
# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="celery beat"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
# m3.medium instance has 1 vCPU. Hence the concurrency is limited to 2
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

this my /etc/systemd/system/celeryd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Beat Service
After=network.target
Requires=gunicorn.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
#Type=forking

User=ravi
Group=ravi
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/celeryd.conf
WorkingDirectory=/home/ravi/deploy/mcam/server/mcam
#ExecStart=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/python manage.py celery -l debug -A mcam beat

ExecStart=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}
#ExecStop=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \

 # --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}

ExecReload=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please help how can i make my celery beat service running in my production server